# Using ASP.NET a bad line of "script" code is inserted at top of default.aspx when run

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am writing a web application using ASP.NET (using VS 2017). The top few lines of my "default.aspx" file look like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link href="StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="help2.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="help2.js?v=2"></script>
</head>
```

However, when I run the app (and it does seem to all work OK) I find an odd line inserted at the top of the "default.aspx" file that is actually passed down to the browser (Chrome, IE, etc). It appears to be trying to alert me about nothing, but nothing happens anyhow because the line is incorrectly formatted (see after the "alert()" where it has the two "script" strings one after another)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('');</script<script type='text/javascript'>alert('
');</script

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1" /><link href="StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link 
href="help2.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="help2.js?v=2"></script>
</head>
```

When using the Developer Tools in either Chrome or IE, this has the effect of causing Console errors... but that is the only effect since it can't give me those alerts to begin with.

My question is: how/why is that line there? Is there any way I can suppress it? I cannot find anything that it would trying to be warning me about... everything seems to work OK anyhow... but I don't want it potentially causing me problems in future. Thanks... Jon

Comment: i would investigate inside `help2.js`

Comment: All the javascript in help2.js runs just fine. I even tried putting the javascript code into a <script> block right in default.aspx rather than linking to it... no difference.

What bothers me the most is that the errant line of script being introduced into the top line is not even formatted correctly. (I mean the top line of the version of "default.aspx" that is being downloaded to the browser client, however that's happening)